# Is it good idea to put NodeJs behind nginx

Tags: node.js

Is it good Idea to put nodeJs behind nginx , also can someone let me know nginx supports http 1.1;

Also how to make sure websockets works with this setup ( nodeJs Behind nginx)

Answer (score 2):

If you want WebSockets, don't put it behind nginx. There might be some way that I don't know of, but [DotCloud doesn't support WebSockets with Node.js because of its reliance on nginx](http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/nodejs/), and they know nginx pretty well.

I assume you want to run your server on Port 80. If node is your main server, that will mean either:

- Running node as root. This is often not ideal because there is potential for bugs in app code and with root access it could cause more damage. If a VM is set aside for a very particular purpose, all backups are made to outside of the VM, and rebuilding is quick, this may not be a big problem, though.
- [Using iptables to forward network traffic to port 80 to a higher-numbered port.](https://gist.github.com/776580) I set this up and I felt like it was a good solution.

**Edit:** You can also run node.js as root and [downgrade to a non-root user with *setuid*](http://onteria.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/dropping-privileges-using-process-setuid-in-node-js/) after binding to Port 80. The Jetty project (a web server for Java) [suggests this technique](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/port80).

Answer (score 0):

nginx doesn't fully support HTTP 1.1. However, work *is* being done and will possibly be integrated into the development branch soon so keep your digits crossed and have a look at [this mailing list thread](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-devel/2011-July/001057.html) to see what I'm talking about (there are patches but I haven't tried them as yet). More discussion [here](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2011-August/028324.html).

Depending on your needs you can do what [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3461/ben-atkin) suggests using IPTables although I would also 'stealth' the high port using the mark module; I've upped a [simple shell script](https://gist.github.com/1174831) that will do it for you.

If you need other applications on 80 you'll need to proxy; [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) is one option but you can keep it all node using the excellent [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).